# socket.io-client and useEffect not getting updated react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I'm trying to get updated react hooks values inside socket on but it's not getting updated values. Whenever I update my react hook values it doesn't reflect inside socket. Below is my code

```
//socketIO in client 

useEffect(() => {

    const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
    socket.on("FromAPI", data => {

      console.log(muteList); // here is my react hook 
    });


  }, []);
```

socket server sends update every 20 seconds. What can I do to get the updated react hook values inside socket

Comment: Depends on what you want to do inside the callback there, other than log the `muteList`

Comment: @CertainPerformance my program sends an alert based on data it receive and the exlusion list which is muteList hooks. The muteList is the list of items based on clicking of buttons. So I compare the muteList and data

Answer (score 1):

If `muteList` happens not to be used for rendering, you can use a ref instead:

```
const muteListRef = useRef([]);
```

and change it with `muteListRef.current = someNewMuteList`.

If `muteList` *is* used for rendering, state is required. One option would be to re-add the listener every time the list changes:

```
const socketRef = useRef();
if (!socketRef.current) {
  socketRef.current = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
}
const [muteList, setMuteList] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  const listener = (data) => {
    console.log(muteList);
    // do other stuff with muteList
  };
  socketRef.current.on('FromAPI', listener);
  // Remove this listener whenever the component unmounts
  // or whenever muteList changes
  return () => socketRef.current.off('FromAPI', listener);
}, [muteList];
```

You could also use *both* a ref and state to solve the problem, but that isn't a very elegant approach.